# Как заставить питон "поймать" момент, когда в буфере обмена появляется картинка?

Tags: python

В двух словах: есть скрипт который извлекает картинку из буфера обмена, затем преобразовывает её в текст (pyteserract) и помещает в буфер обмена уже текст с картинки.

Собственно сам вопрос: как заставить питон отловить момент, когда в буфере обмена появляется картинка, и чтобы он сам начал выполнение скрипта (как обновляется буфер обмена?)

Сейчас у меня стоит всё на горячих клавишах, хотелось бы попробовать без них.

```
import pytesseract
import keyboard
import time
import os
import win10toast

from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image

def foo():
    print("                                                      "*10)

    print("               __.....__                              ")
    print("           .-''         '.                            ")
    print("     .|   /     .-''\"--.  `.                     .|   ")
    print("   .' |_ /     /________\   \ ____     _____   .' |_  ")
    print(" .'     ||                  |`.   \  .'    / .'     | ")
    print("'--.  .-'\    .-------------'  `.  `'    .' '--.  .-' ")
    print("   |  |   \    '-.____...---.    '.    .'      |  |   ")
    print("   |  |    `.             .'     .'     `.     |  |   ")
    print("   |  '.'    `''-...... -'     .'  .'`.   `.   |  '.' ")
    print("   |   /                     .'   /    `.   `. |   /  ")
    print("   `'-'                     '----'       '----'`'-'   ")
    print("______________________________________________________")
    print("                                                      ")
    print("                                                      ")
    print("                                                      ")
    
    
    im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
    
    image_path = "C:/Windows/Temp"
    im.save(f"{image_path}/TEXT.png")
    
    # time.sleep (1)

    img = Image.open(f"{image_path}/TEXT.png")
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

    # custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 13'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="rus")
    print(text)

    pyperclip.copy(text)
    
    os.remove(f"{image_path}/TEXT.png")
    
    print("                                                      "*4)
    print("[INFO] Текст успешно сохранён в буфер обмена.")

keyboard.add_hotkey('Alt + q', foo)
keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Alt + q')

# with open('text.txt', 'a') as f:
#    f.write(text+"\n")
```

Comment: Ну самое простое -> ты когда копируешь файл или объект в буфер - в основном это лишь путь до самого файла или объекта, с которым работать очень легко, трудностей не должно возникать вроде ;)

Comment: Я про то - что если, скопированный путь вида, например -> C:/User/foder/folder_two/1.jpg - отследить что это картинка проще легкого. Достаточно вырвать формат те - .jpg. Это можно с помощью например регулярных выражений? - \.\w+

Comment: То есть, любой объект который я сохраняю в буфер обмена имеет какой то путь, по которому этот файл можно выцепить? И если это так, то как найти этот путь?

Comment: Эм вывести что хранит буфер на пример и посмотреть.